# How to validate open id in Shared hosting?

Tags: hosting, openid, shared

I have a site hosted on a shared hosting, I am building a forum and want users to register through OpenId. The problem is I am not able to connect to OpenId providers like Google and Yahoo, because my server doesnt connect to them!

Is there a way to use client side OpenId validation using ajax (XmlHttp) or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  OpenID relying parties MUST have the capability for outbound HTTP requests.  If anyone tells you differently, it's not OpenID and/or it's not secure.

Comment: Well, it makes sense. I read more about OpenId and felt that if I write client side script to exchange the secret then I am opening a secret door for the bad guys! I have asked my service provider to provide me access to outbound HTTP.